# External Hard Drive Ownership

Tags: windows, permissions, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, ownership

When i copy a file over to my external hard drive, everything works fine, until i plug it into another computer. All the sudden the files i copied require admin rights to be read or writen to, on all other computers except the on I've copied the files from.
I have tried many things i thought could work, but can't get the drive back to behaving normally.

Here's what i've tried:

- Scanning drive with scannow and riht clicking the drive and Tools -->
  Error-Checking
- Setting the entire drives ownership to user "everyone"

Things i haven't tried:

- Formatting 2TB Worth of data (Which i'd rather not)
- Checking if it requires root on different operating systems, like "linux" and "mac os"

At the moment i can't check mac os, because i don't own a mac. And i know nobody who does. Linux i will try right after writing this. A temporary solution for now works as following but isn't efficcient in any way:

1. Copy the file
2. Take ownership of copied file
3. Change Read and Write access to "Everyone"

Right now this is the drive with the most of my valueable data on it, so i don't really want to format it or change anything to the partition table, just in case it gets currupted. If anyone has expierienced this strange issue before, please, tell me how you fixed it, because I'm runnning out of ideas..

Comment: macOS is the easy one - you can just 'Get Info' on the drive & check the box for 'ignore ownership on this volume'. The Mac feels no obligation to respect permissions on anything but the boot volume [or boot/data pair on newer OSes] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgImi.png

Comment: NTFS permissions on external drives don't make any sense (as some OS just ignore them like Linux). Therefore you should set Everybody Full Read & Write access and propagate that on all files and subdirectories.

Comment: You can format the drive as FAT32 and the problem will go away too, but keep in mind that a format clears the drive, so copy all data off first, then format, then copy it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ownership doesn't matter. The only kind of access automatically granted to the owner is the ability to *edit the access list* (in case the access list itself doesn't grant that), but it doesn't otherwise affect whether you can read or write the files themselves.

To actually achieve unlimited access, you need to add "Everyone" to the *access list* and allow it "Full Control" in the "Permissions" section.

You might also want to open the "Advanced" window and check "Replace all child object permissions" (this will perform a one-time reset, just in case any files had inheritance disabled previously).

[image]
[image]

From command line:

1. Reset permissions:

   ```
   icacls X:\ /reset /t
   ```

   This recursively re-enables inheritance and removes all explicitly added permission entries on all child items. Running this command is equivalent to the "Replace all child object permission entries" action in GUI.
2. Grant "Everyone" full-control permission:

   ```
   icacls X:\ /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F
   ```

   On non-English systems, this command can be written using the SID for 'Everyone', rather than the name (which may be localized, but the SID always remains the same):

   ```
   icacls X:\ /grant "*S-1-1-0:(OI)(CI)F"
   ```

   Specifying `(OI)(CI)` is equivalent to choosing "Applies to: This folder, subfolders, and files" in the GUI. It marks the grant "inheritable" so that the permission will automatically be added to child items – hence the lack of `/t` option.

   (You would need to use `/t` if you chose to not reset permissions and had folders with ACL inheritance disabled.)

---

Scanning the disk for errors won't give you any results, because this is not an error – it's normal behavior of the file permissions system.

"Formatting" a drive discards its previous contents and creates a completely blank filesystem, leaving you with 0B worth of data. You don't want to do that.

Comment: I've Tried setting the ownership to Everyone, and it worked.
The only problem was that the second command you specified didn't contain the "/t" parameter, which means i doesn't apply to any child objects.
Second problem was that the user Everyone doesn't Exist because I'm using a computer with a different language. For dutch computers that would go from:
icacls X:\ /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F
to:
icacls X:\ /grant Iedereen:(OI)(CI)F /t
I'll Mark this question as fixed, but just in case sopmeone else has the same problem. Can you edit the answer you gave to contain what i just said?

Comment: The `/t` parameter was deliberately omitted, because the ACE is inheritable (that's the `(oi)(ci)` part – object inherit & container inherit) and so it doesn't need to be explicitly added to children. Icacls will automatically propagate inheritance even without that option. (Child objects which had inheritance disabled should have had it re-enabled by /reset.)